# user setup in keycloak with organization information

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am looking for best recommended approach to create / manage users with organization name and id in Keycloak ( through a html form )

I read following documentation but cannot find a straight forward way to manage users there with organization name and Org id.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/

The approach that i used was using a custom attributes but i am not sure if that is the recommened approach or not.

**Step-1**, For every user create a custom attribute "OrgId" with value unique to that organization lets say 1.

**Step-2**, For the Client, that the user belongs to, define a protocol mapper "OrgId"

**Step-3**, Create a table for Organziation into our system, add an Organization entry there when first user for that organization is created.

**Problem i am trying to solve**: We need to keep track of various actions that users belongs to an organization is doing, such as we need to keep track which organization bought what type of products from our system